Find function $f$ knowing the primitive
Knowing that the function $F$ is a primitive of the function $f$, I have to find the value of $a$ and $b$ and find $f$.
$$F(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    ax+b,  &\text{if $x<0$} \\ 
    \ln^2{x}+1, &\text{if $x\ge1$}
\end{cases}$$
I've got that
$$
f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=
\begin{cases} 
    a,  &\text{if $x<0$} \\ 
    \frac{2\ln{x}}{x}, &\text{if $x\ge1$}
\end{cases}
$$
but I don't know what to do next. There's no point in finding $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 0^-}F(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}F(x)$.
Is it possible that the exercise is actually wrong or am I missing something?

Ah I see ... I agree that the problem would make much more sense if $x<0$ were supposed to be $x<1$.

I think both piecewise points are supposed to be at $1$. You then have to find $a$ and $b$ that make $F$ continuous and differentiable.

How do i close this question?

write your solution as an answer then mark it correct

I tried solving the problem by replacing $x<0$ with $x<1$.
So, we have:
$$F(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    ax+b,  &\text{if $x<1$} \\ 
    \ln^2{x}+1, &\text{if $x\ge1$}
\end{cases}$$
$$
f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=
\begin{cases} 
    a,  &\text{if $x<1$} \\ 
    \frac{2\ln{x}}{x}, &\text{if $x\ge1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then i found $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}F(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}F(x)$:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}F(x)=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}(ax+b)=a+b
$$$$
\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}F(x)=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}(\ln^2{x})=1
$$
$$
\text{and since $\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}F(x)=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}F(x)$ then $a+b=1$}
$$
I tried also finding left-hand and right-hand derivatives of $F(1)$:
$$
F'_{-}(1)=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}\frac{F(x)-F(1)}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}\frac{ax+b-\ln^2{1}-1}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}\frac{ax+b-1}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^-}\frac{a}{1}=a
$$
$$
F'_{+}(1)=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}\frac{F(x)-F(1)}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}\frac{\ln^2{x}+1-\ln^2{1}-1}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}\frac{\ln^2{x}}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 1^+}\frac{2\ln{x}}{x}=0
$$
$$
\text{and since $F'_{-}(1)=F'_{+}(1)$ then $a=0$ and $b=1-a=1$}
$$
